# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was working in my app when this message appeared:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/jesus/Downloads/P10_Patrones -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/jesus/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=6970002559981463517 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\jesus\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.3 -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\jesus\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.3\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/jesus/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.9 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/jesus/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server/p10_patrones_ae94d5a5/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\jesus\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-9574467152744854472-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.52.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-model-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.13.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/intellij-deps-fastutil-8.4.1-4.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/commons-lang3-3.10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/httpcore-4.4.13.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/httpclient-4.5.12.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/asm-all-9.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.52.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/platform-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/apkzlib-4.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/apksig-4.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/android-jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdk-common-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.repository-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdklib-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.layoutlib-api-27.0.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.manifest-merger-27.0.0.0.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 54532 5b75674f-c727-4514-9b83-63eceada03a6 C:/Users/jesus/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I don't know how to solve it. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some components are used SLF4J logging. I solved this problem like this:

```xml
    <!-- log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J Bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also you can take a look at this post as well: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html